# Proving that context-freeness of $L(M)$ is not semi-decidable using Rice's theorem

Tags: computability, semi-decidability

This is a question from an exam I did today:

> Given $M$, a turing machine, we need to decide the following:
>
> 1) $M$ halts on every input
>
> 2) The language of $M$ is CFL

My question is, can I prove that this problem is not in $RE$ (recursively enumerable) using Rice's theorem? I understand that Rice's theorem works for languages and not machines, and when first looking at it, number 1 is a property of a machine not the language. But what I said, is that actually it *is* a property of a language: $M$ halts on every input *iff* $L(M)$ is decidable! (in $R$), so we can use Rice.

What do you think?

Comment: What is "Rice theory"? Do you mean Rice's theorem? If so, which version? You may want to check out [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19769/is-regularity-of-the-language-accepted-by-a-given-turing-machine-a-semi-decidabl/19781#19781), [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/perplexed-by-rices-theorem/6928#6928) and [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9703/intuition-about-decidability) question.

Comment: Rice's theorem considering non-trivial properties.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not true that $M$ halts on every input iff $L(M)$ is decidable. Indeed, $L(M)$ can be decidable even if $M$ doesn't halt on every input. Consider for example the machine which never halts on any input—the empty language is certainly decidable.

Rice's theorem considers properties of *partial functions*. The partial function is the one computed by the Turing machine, with $\bot$ representing the case that the Turing machine doesn't halt on a specific input. If a machine $M$ always halts then the corresponding function is total—never attains the value $\bot$. This is a property of partial functions, and fits within the framework of Rice's theorem.

If you're not sure about this, have a look at the proof that the language of total Turing machines (ones that halt on all inputs) is not decidable.

Comment: So, overall, we can't use Rice for the problem I described, yes?

Comment: On the contrary, I was trying to demonstrate that while Rice's theorem can be used, your own approach fails.

Comment: You made me understand why my proof is wrong. But doesn't that also say that I am also wrong by applying Rice's theory?

Comment: No, you're just applying the theorem in the wrong way. I suggest you have a look at the proof that the language of total Turing machines is undecidable. It addresses the part that bothers you.

Comment: Which one are you referring to? The ones I reached do a proof by reduction.

Comment: Well, a proof using Rice's theorem.